# how to reslove Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 140 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, android-emulator

i keep getting this message whenever i try to run my flutter code on an android emulator

i've tried other solutions like:
1- update gradle
2- use another emulator
3- run `flutter doctor` and check all the requriments
4- update android emulator

but the problem is that,
it first run on windows naturally but when i try to run it on an emulator nothing happen
and when i go back to to run it on windows it says

`Unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON at position 140`

help :')